# BizTalk: BTAHL72XReceivePipeline Pipeline Component

Tags: biztalk, hl7, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-pipelines

I've set-up two applications, one with FILE Receive Port and the other with a Send Port subscribing to that Receive Port with filter set as `BTS.ReceivePortName == {ReceivePortNameHere}`. I'm using BizTalk 2013 R2.

In the Receive Port, I'm using the pipeline 'BTAHL72XReceivePipeline'. And, in the  Send Port, I'm using the pipeline 'BTAHL72XSendPipeline'.

When I drop a HL7 message into the Receive Port file location, it produces the error:

> The Messaging engine failed to process a message submitted by
>   adapter:FILE Source URL:E:\InboundToBizTalk\*.hl7. Details:The
>   published message could not be routed because no subscribers were
>   found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port
>   has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary
>   for subscription evaluation have not been promoted. Please use the
>   Biztalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure.

However, I do have a subscription set. Why is this error occurring? Is there an issue with the pipeline component or the way I am using it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the pipelines on both ports to to pass thru?  That would eliminate the Pipelines as being the issue if there is still an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be ACK which could not be routed therefore causing the whole flow to error. For an MLLP transport type, it is two way thus the ACK can be routed. For a FILE transport type, it is one way therefore ACK needs to be accounted for separately.

To get around this, another port was created which would subscribe to the ACK.

Answer (score 0):

The by far most likely causes:

1. A typo between the Receive Port Name and the value in the Filter.
2. The Send Port is not Enlisted or Started.
3. Do not use quotes in the filter property.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, checked it multiple times, it's not that. :(

Answer (score 0):

On the Group Overview page search for "Subscriptions" and filter based on your Send port name.
Verify that you see an activation Subscription and confirm that the filter conditions on the subscription are correct.

Comment: The subscription is present and visible there.

Comment: Could you check the Suspended Message for its promoted properties and check if the ReceivePortName property is pointing to the right value.

Comment: The Receive Port entry is there but still not working. I got it to work by subscribing to an alternative promoted properties as an 'or' filter. Still uncertain on why Receive Port filter entry isn't working.